# How to draw line in Directx12?

Tags: matrix, directx, directx-12

I want to draw line between two points `(x1,y1,z1)` `(x2,y2,z2)`. I want to have possibility to change this line start and end point at any time.

To draw something in DirectX you need to create vertex buffer as a fundament, and then, create instances, which can be transformed, for example, via constant buffer.

If we talk about primitives you need to pass world matrix, that describes offset, rotation or scale, to vertex shader to multiply it on each vertex and then on view and projection matrix.

But what operations should I do, if I have line that vertices described by vertex buffer as `(x1,y1,z1)` `(x2,y2,z2)` and now I want to make them `(x1’,y1’,z1’)` `(x2’,y2’,z2’)`?

Comment: Look at ``PrimitiveBatch`` in [DirectX Tool Kit for DX12](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK12/wiki/Getting-Started).

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn okay, can I use it under Visual Studio 2015? I have created a new project, installed DirectxTK12 via NuGet, get Your sample from GitHub where You draw grid, but when try to build, linker says there are unresolved symbols. I have also included all dependencies according to Braynzarsoft article

Comment: Did you use [this nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/directxtk12_desktop_2015/2019.12.17.1)? Are you using VS 2015 Update 3?

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn yes, I right clicked on project, choose exactly directxtk12 for visual studio 15. I don’t have error that Ide can’t find header, I have a linker error. First two was about Ro, so I found that I have to link `RuntimeObject.lib` or `windowsapp.lib`. After, first two error disappeared but still there are unresolved symbols in game class methods. VS 2015 Update 3 - don’t know, I check

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn I had to add Your sample cpp files using Visual Studio, not just drop to project folder. However, I still have problems. In `Game.cpp` there was written `Model::CreateFromSDKMESH(device, L"tiny.sdkmesh")` instead of `Model::CreateFromSDKMESH( L"tiny.sdkmesh", device)`

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn and I have three linker error - two DeviceResources.obj link2001 error unresolved symbol `_DXGI_DEBUG_ALL` and debug_dxgi. And one - DirectxTK12.lib(ResourceUploadBatch.obj):  link2001 unresolved "_IID_ID3D12Device"

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn changing build property from Debug to Release fixed first two problems, but I still have DirectxTK12.lib(ResourceUploadBatch.obj): link2001 unresolved "_IID_ID3D12Device" issue

Comment: DirectX apps should link to ``dxguid.lib`` to get various COM IID values. You also should use ``uuid.lib`` for WIC. See [the wiki](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK12/wiki/DirectXTK#dependencies).

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn, also I saw one of Your previous answer. You said, that if video card doesn’t supports dx12 it’s impossible to run app with DirectX12 Tool Kit, but in pure directx 12 it is possible (so do I). Can I somehow run my app, if I will get success in build? Or should switch to Dx11?

Comment: You could in theory run WARP12 software device, but you are probably better off using DirectX 11.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210894/discussion-between-artur-and-chuck-walbourn).